# My phone uses excessive data 0

Tags: mobile-data

I have a sansung s7.  It is gobbling up data.  I've disabled as many programs as i dare from running in the background but no help.  Is there anything i can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

That's not good to hear! If your [Samsung S7 Edge is rooted](http://mobilesiri.com/galaxy-s7-edge-exynos-root/) then I would suggest running an application such as [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en) and setting custom rules to block applications communicating to web-servers etc.

You did not mention how much data you have to play with, but you could go ahead and install an application such as [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog&hl=en) to view what applications are using an excessive amount of data. (This can also be viewed in `Settings --> Data`)

I would suggest you ensure your [accounts are not set to sync frequently](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9342/how-can-i-shut-off-sync-or-change-its-frequency), and that a[pps are not updating over 4G](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/features/how-to-turn-off-automatic-app-updates-in-android-ios-windows-phone-81-windows-81-634685).

Lastly if that all does not help, here are some good forums:

Android Authority - [Android OS destroying my Data!](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge/687299-android-os-destroying-my-data-s7-edge.html)

Samsung Forum - [OS Application using extensive data](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/S7-android-os-app-using-a-lot-of-data/td-p/27555)

Reddit - [S7 Edge using heaps of data](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS7/comments/4ewy2x/strangeexcessive_data_usage_since_getting_s7/)

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling background data and also stopping sync services like photo backup. Sometimes cloud storage services provide the option of keeping the cloud files on the device. Which means if this facility is on, any large file may be downloaded to you device from the server to keep sync.